# Auto size row height to match expandable textbox

Tags: vba, excel

I have inserted a textbox into a row range. The purpose of the textbox is to allow for more dynamic formating of input text than is available by just entering text into a cell.  I would like the textbox to be expandable, which is easily done in the text box settings, and have the corresponding row expand along with it which is not so easy.  I have cells with data below the text box and when it expands now it covers those cells.

I would appreciate any assistence with vba code that would allow the row height to automatically adjust as the text box height adjusts.  I have searched online and while I found 1 similar question but the answer given suggested using a user form textbox that feeds to a cell but that does not meet my formatting needs.  Also just to be clear, this is the text box that is found from the insert menu in Excel.

I imagine the code would look something like:

```
On change event (linked to textbox #)'not sure if this is possible
dim x as long, commentcell_rng as range
set commentcell_rng as thisworkbook.sheets("Sheet1").range("A81:N81")
    x = textbox # height 'Not sure how to return textbox height also I don't know if text box height matches cell height unit of measure
commentcell_rng.entirerow.height = x
```

I am not sure if I am going in the right direction but hope this outlines what I want to happen.

Comment: Shapes do not have events in Excel and do not trigger `Worksheet_Change` events.  So, unfortunately this will not be feasible.  You could use a `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event, but the user would have to select a different cell before the event would run.  What formatting are you trying to achieve that can't be done in a cell?

Comment: What sort of textbox have you inserted to your worksheet? just the regular activex textbox?

Comment: I've only briefly looked, but couldn't see a way to easily resize the textbox (like a drag handle type deal) option. If you were to remove the ability to resize the textbox via something like that and relied solely on the dimensions of the range then it should be a bit simpler?

Comment: @NickSlash, based on his description he's using a `TextBox` shape not an `ActiveX` or forms control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot trigger events in the shape, as Mr. Mascaro has mentioned.
To set a row to the height of a shape use

```
Range("A1").RowHeight = sheet1.Shapes("name_of_shape").Height
```

No unit conversion required.
But, make sure the shape properties are set to "Don't move or size with cells"
The only way to trigger from changes to text inside a shape is to run a timer event, which is possible via a few methods, although a pain to code. Another option maybe be a button for the user to confirm the text changes, which can be triggered in a click event, then set the row height.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same request and have just found a solution, which incorporates @rayzinnz piece of code.

I have a text box, which resizes downwards when more text is input. The row height related to the text line should resize accordingly to keep order in the rest of the sheet.

The following code worked for me:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Cells.Count = 1 And IsEmpty(Target) Or Not IsEmpty(Target)Then
    Range("A9").RowHeight = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Scope_IL_Definition_TB").Height
End If

End Sub
```

This was placed in the specific Worksheet's code.
When the user stops typing and clicks outside the textbox, the row height is adjusted.